# XML element restriction using XPath query in XSD1.1 assert

Tags: xml, xpath, assert, restriction, xsd-1.1

I wrote "music.xsd" for validating the below "music.xml" file. In the music file there are two specializations styleSpec and ensembleSpec.

```
 <specialization name="styleSpec">
    <entity name="Symphonic">
    </entity>    
 </specialization>
```

and

```
 <specialization name="ensembleSpec">
    <entity name="Orchestra">
    </entity>   
 </specialization>
```

"styleSpec" permitted entities are Symphonic, Folk and Jazz.

"ensembleSpec" permitted entities are Orchestra, SmallGroup and Soloist.

I want to add the following restrictions:

1. if the entity inside styleSpec is Symphonic then the entity inside ensembleSpec must be Orchestra.
2. if the entity inside styleSpec is Folk then the entity inside ensembleSpec must be either SmallGroup or Soloist.
3. if the entity inside styleSpec is Jazz then the entity inside ensembleSpec must be either Orchestra or SmallGroup.

I am able to do this in another XSD file (another.xsd,given below) but when i add that assert statement in music.xsd it is not working.

How can i solve this problem?

## music.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<entity xmlns:vc="http://www.w3.org/2007/XMLSchema-versioning"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="music.xsd" 
 name="MusicPerformances"> 

<multiAspect name="musicPerformancesMAsp">
 <entity name="MusicPerformance">

 <specialization name="styleSpec">
  <entity name="Symphonic">
  </entity>    
 </specialization>

 <specialization name="ensembleSpec">
  <entity name="Orchestra">
  </entity>   
 </specialization>

 </entity>
</multiAspect> 

</entity>
```

## music.xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
elementFormDefault="qualified"
xmlns:vc="http://www.w3.org/2007/XMLSchema-versioning" vc:minVersion="1.1">

<xs:complexType name="aspectType">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" ref="entity"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="name" use="required"/>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="multiAspectType">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" ref="entity"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="name" use="required"/>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="specializationType">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" ref="entity"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="name" use="required"/>
</xs:complexType>


<xs:complexType name="varType"> 
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" ref="entity"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="name" use="required"/>

</xs:complexType>


<xs:element name="entity">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:element ref="aspect"/>
                <xs:element ref="specialization"/>
                <xs:element ref="multiAspect"/>
                <xs:element ref="var"/>

            </xs:choice>            

        </xs:sequence>

        <xs:attribute name="name" use="required"/>

        <xs:assert test="every $x in .//entity satisfies empty($x//*[@name = $x/@name])"/>
        <!--   

        <xs:assert test=
            **// Maybe have to add XPath query here. But I am not sure where 
              i will add.**
        />

          --> 
    </xs:complexType> 

    <xs:unique name="entityunqall">
        <xs:selector xpath="*/entity"/>            
        <xs:field xpath="@name"/>
    </xs:unique> 


</xs:element>

<xs:element name="aspect" type="aspectType"/>
<xs:element name="multiAspect" type="multiAspectType"/>
<xs:element name="specialization" type="specializationType"/>
<xs:element name="var" type="varType"/>
```

The another.xml file is working with another.xsd properly.

## another.xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
elementFormDefault="qualified" 
xmlns:vc="http://www.w3.org/2007/XMLSchema-versioning" vc:minVersion="1.1"> 

<xs:element name="styleSpec">       
    <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:enumeration value="Symphonic" />
            <xs:enumeration value="Folk" />
            <xs:enumeration value="Jazz" />
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:element> 

<xs:element name="ensembleSpec">       
    <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:enumeration value="Orchestra" />
            <xs:enumeration value="SmallGroup" />
            <xs:enumeration value="Soloist" />
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>

<xs:element name="MusicalPerformance">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>                 
            <xs:element ref="styleSpec"/>
            <xs:element ref="ensembleSpec"/>                      
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:assert test="(styleSpec = 'Symphonic' and ensembleSpec=('Orchestra'))
            or
            (styleSpec = 'Folk' and ensembleSpec=('SmallGroup','Soloist'))
            or
            (styleSpec = 'Jazz' and ensembleSpec=('Orchestra','SmallGroup'))
            "/>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>



</xs:schema>
```

## another.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<MusicalPerformance xmlns:vc="http://www.w3.org/2007/XMLSchema-versioning"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="another.xsd">
    <styleSpec>Folk</styleSpec>
    <ensembleSpec>Soloist</ensembleSpec>     
</MusicalPerformance>
```

## Edit

I have changed the music file and new file is given below:

## music.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<entity xmlns:vc="http://www.w3.org/2007/XMLSchema-versioning"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="musicalperformances.xsd" 
name="MusicPerformances">

  <multiAspect name="MusicPerformancesMAsp">
  <entity name="MusicPerformance">
  <aspect name="MusicPerformanceDec">
    <entity name="Music">
      <specialization name="styleSpec">
        <entity name="Jazz">
        </entity>
      </specialization>
    </entity>
    <entity name="Performer">
      <specialization name="ensembleSpec">
        <entity name="SmallGroup">
        </entity>
      </specialization>
    </entity>
  </aspect>
  </entity>
  </multiAspect>


  </entity>
```

Comment: Tell us exactly what you did, and exactly how it failed. Telling us that you tried something unspecified and that it failed in an unspecified way isn't helpful.

Comment: Dear Michael Kay, I have tested that using:                                        every $x in .//specialization[1] satisfies ($x/entity='Symphonic'),  every $x in .//specialization[2] satisfies ($x/entity='Orchestra')                                   but it is not working. I have to combine these two assert statements but i am not able to do this so far. Hope you will understand this.

Comment: I have also tried________  <xs:assert test=" if((//specialization[1]/entity) = 'Symphonic') then (//specialization[2]/entity='Orchestra') else false()" />________ But it gives warning- An assert XPath expression such as (' if((//specialization[1]/entity) = 'Symphonic') then (//specialization[2]/entity='Orchestra') else false()') containing / or //, on the schema type '#AnonType_entity', cannot yield a valid result (since an assert tree is rooted at a parentless element).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, the assertion needs to go on the parent element of the two specialization elements (i.e. at the level of the `multiAspect` element). You haven't made it clear in your question or in your comments where you put the assertion, which may indicate that you haven't realised how important it is to get this right.

The rules are then very simple, for example:

> if the entity inside styleSpec is Symphonic then the entity inside
>   ensembleSpec must be Orchestra.

```
test="if (specialization[@name='styleSpec']/entity/@name='Symphonic')
      then specialization(@name='ensembleSpec']/entity/@name='Orchestra' 
      else true()"
```

Comment: Dear Michael Kay, thank you. I have changed the music file and new file is also added in the EDIT section. So i changed my assert statement like given here and it is working. ______________________<xs:assert test="if(aspect/entity/specialization[@name='styleSpec']/entity/@name='Symphonic') then (aspect/entity/specialization[@name='ensembleSpec']/entity/@name='Orchestra') else true()" />

Comment: Now, I want to know is there any way so that i can write the query like given here and it will work. ______ test ="if (//Music/*[@name='Jazz']) then (//Performer/*[@name='Orchestra' or //Performer/*[@name='SmallGroup') else true()".

Comment: A leading "//" in an assertion expression is probably wrong because an assertion only has access to the subtree on which the assertion is defined, not to the entire document, whereas "//" takes you to the root of the document.

Comment: <entity name="Music">
      <specialization name="styleSpec">
        <entity name="Jazz">
        </entity>
      </specialization>
    </entity>

Comment: <entity name="Music">
      <specialization name="styleSpec">
        <entity name="Jazz">
        </entity>
      </specialization>
    </entity>    May be i didn't make my question clear. I want to know,  instead of using aspect or entity or specialization can i use the name like Music  or Performer in the XPath query. I didn't find anything like this in your book and other books i read so far. All the examples are using the elements and its attributes which are presents in the .xsd file. I think its not possible but i want to confirm from you.

Comment: If you use an element name "Music" in your assertion and there is no element named "Music" in your instance document (or your schema), that's legal but completely pointless as the expression will select nothing. Saxon will generally give you a warning that it's pointless.